# RegEx for capturing an attribute value in a HTML element

Tags: html, regex, html-parsing, regex-greedy, html-parser

I have a problem to extract text in the html tag using regex.

I want to extract the text from the following html code.

```
<a href="http://google.com/" target="_self" title="TEXTDATA" class="encyclopedia">Google</a>
```

The result:

```
TEXTDATA
```

> I want to extract only the text `TEXTDATA`

I have tried but I have not succeeded.

Comment: In which language regex ex python, js

Comment: Please include the code that you have tried, without a specific issue/problem to solve the question will likely be closed.

Comment: I want to scrape the data using the wordpress automatic plugin, from the php code

Answer (score 2):

Here we want to swipe the string up to a left boundary, then collect our desired data, then continue swiping to the end of string, if we like:

```
<.+title="(.+?)"(.*)
```

[image]

```js
const regex = /<.+title="(.+?)"(.*)/gm;
const str = `<a href="http://google.com/" target="_self" title="TEXTDATA" class="encyclopedia">Google</a>`;
const subst = `$1`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, it can be modified or changed in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/QlY1jf/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) also helps to visualize the expressions.

[image]

#### PHP

```
$re = '/<.+title="(.+?)"(.*)/m';
$str = '<a href="http://google.com/" target="_self" title="TEXTDATA" class="encyclopedia">Google</a>';
$subst = '$1';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex:

```regex
title=\"([^\"]*)\"
```

See:
[Regex](https://regex101.com/r/MB4Jaz/1)

Answer (score -1):

`<a href="http://google.com/" target="_self" class="encyclopedia">Google</a>`

Remvoe Title and try

Comment: How will this help select / extract the text `TEXTDATA`? In fact, it is completely removed from your answer...

Comment: add Name="Google" else hint = "Google" , Value="Google"